# Django render: How to instance selected items in Select2 Jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-select2

I'm filtering some data using Raw method, it allows the user to select multiple values in a field using Select2 plugin, I get request.POST of each field, do filtering stuff, then I return the context like this:

```
context = {
    'form': MyForm(request.POST),
    'results': results,
}
return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

It's suppossed to show the user which fields were selected when I get back the results to show them, but when the form renders I get selected only the first value of the list (retrieved from POST). Do I have to set something else? Or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:** Render the input widget from Django Form:

```
equipo = ChoiceField(
        widget=Select(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control input-sm', 'multiple': 'multiple'}
        )
    )
```

Also, I'm not saving, I'm just retrieving values to apply filters using `raw`method and giving back the rawquery result.

View:

```
class MedicionView(View):

    def __init__(self):
        self.template_name = "medicion/grid.html"

    def get(self, request):

        form = MedicionFiltersForm()
        odometros = Odometro.objects.all()
        equipos = Equipo.objects.all()
        results = Odometro.objects.raw('''
            select
            ....

                ''')[:100]

        contexto = {
            'form': form,
            'results': results,
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, contexto)

    def post(self, request):
        # Retrieve data 
        form = MedicionFiltersForm(request.POST)
        equipos = request.POST.getlist('equipo')
        odometros = request.POST.getlist('odometro')
        tipo = request.POST.get('tipo')

        # business stuff

        results = Odometro.objects.raw('''
           select
            ...

                ''', [odometros, tipos, equipos])

        # More business stuff

        # return request.POST in form 
        contexto = {
            'form': form,
            'results': results,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, contexto)
```

M2M does not even exist in my models, I just use multiple values to make use of SQL `WHERE IN` clause in `raw` method.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and how you're setting up and configuring Select2 to your question.

Comment: is there a reason you are not simply using `multiple="multiple"`?

Comment: also please include your view here. I'm suspecting you are not `m2m save`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue in a not so nice method but it works:

I passed to a list of integers the values retrieved by the component in POST method and then dumped it into a JSON

```
lista_equipos = request.POST.getlist('equipo')
equipos_lista = [int(item) for item in lista_equipos]
equipos_json = json.dumps(equipos_lista)
```

I return the JSON in the context:

```
context = {
    # some extra variables
    'equipos_lista': equipos_json
}
```

In the template I retrieve this json and set the values into select2 component. Don't miss about the trigger method!

```
<script>
    var array_equipos = {{ equipos_lista }};
    $('#id_equipo').val(array_equipos);
    $('#id_equipo').trigger('change');

 </script>
```